# Return multiple image files from web api method .net core

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a client in React that needs to accept a bunch of images from the server.

At each request, 3 pictures need to show.

I'm trying to figure out a way to send multiple pictures, but all I can find is adding only one file:

```
// GET api/Picture/lower_0000_012
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPictureAsync(string id)
{
    var res = Task.Run(() => _repo.GetPictureSet(id));
    return Ok(await res);
}
```

And in a mock repository class, I have this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetPictureSet(string id)
{
     var path = $@"**folderDirectory**/{id}"; //this folder has 3 files in it
     return PhysicalFile(path, "image/jpeg");
}
```

I still didn't implement anything in the mock repository class because I don't know how to handle it.

If I need to show 3 pictures in the client, should I ask for 3 of them separately?

Comment: I would request each image separately. Implementing something that tries to send multiple images per request doesn't seem like the most logical solution but you could (for instance) send them down in a zip and process the zip to extract the batch of images.

Comment: @scgough, i dont think a client app should handle a zip file..

Comment: No, agreed. I'd get each image delivered separately.